# Return JSONResponse before updating database in django, python2

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

Im having a project running on python2.7. The project is old but still its necessary to update the database when a request is received. But the update process takes time and ends up with a timeout. Is there anyway return JsonResponse/Httpresponse, before updating the database so that timeout doesn't occur. I know its not logical to do so, but its a temporary fix.

Also, i cant use async since its python2

Comment: Where code? Do you use DRF?

Comment: code is bit large. and i dont use DRF. Like i mentioned its an old project and i just need to return status 200 and then proceed to database updation. requesting endpoint doesnt wait as long as time taken for updating database @hansTheFranz

Comment: You need some background job like celery v4. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use  multiprocessing or multithreading this will execute your task with another process and  send HTTP response fastly to client-side